# relating business and products with custom taxonomy?

Tags: posts, taxonomy, customization

This isn't a code question so much as a how would you do that kind of question.

What I can't figure out is how to relate businesses to the the products that they sell.

If I've got a custom post type and related taxonomy for a product (post type of product and taxonomies for price, quality,  etc.). And I've got the same for businesses (custom post type and custom meta for location details).

How do I relate a product to a business?

If a user adds a product to the database (ie creates a new post) how can I associate this item with the store it was purchased at?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Store the post id of the business in a post meta field of the product (`_business_id`), or create a custom table, because [post meta look-ups are rather slow](http://www.taylorlovett.com/web-development/taxonomy-vs-post-meta-queries/).